# __targv is NULL in my MFC windows application. argc == 1

Tags: c++, mfc, argv, afx

I have a windows application setup as follows:
Debug - builds an exe which statically links the libraries it uses
Release - builds an exe which links to a DLL

I've just created the release version, the only difference being is that one of the libraries that is used, is now being built as a DLL.

When I execute my application, whenever the command line arguments are accessed it crashes.  This is due to __targv being NULL, yet argc == 1.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Show how you declared the `main` function and tell us more about the used environment (MSVC version, solution configuration etc).

Comment: What happens if you add an argument?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in __targv is the path and name of the current executable.

This is why the argument count is at 1. Try printing on screen the content of `__targv[0]`, you should see something like `C:/.../.../foobar.exe` (where `.../...` is the path to your executable and `foobar.exe` being the exe)

Comment: Then why is __targv NULL vs. having data in __targv[0]?

Comment: Could you post some of your code and output so that we could see what's really going on?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions and help.

If anyone is interested, here is some closure to the problem.  Also, if anyone else ever has this problem, this is for them:

In the processing of creating the DLL, I had to switch the C runtime library to MD (DLL type) and (I thought) MFC linking configuration (UseOfMFC).

I had mistakenly mixed UseOfMFC types, which I believe was messing up _targv as well as causing exceptions when calling any AFX functions.

I revisited the project, changing all configurations to using the DLL type CRT and left the UseOfMFC untouched.  This fixed the problems I was having.